# Route url which is recommended to use underscore or dash?

Tags: url, routes, info

I'm getting a little confused about choosing the more right `URL` i would appreciate if you could recommend which one is better

```
domain.com/admin/manage_vehicles
```

or

```
domain.com/admin/manage-vehicles
```

or

```
domain.com/admin/manage/vehicles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd way is the most user friendly way to make a URL.
It will be more useful when you have multiple routes of that same category.

```
domain.com/admin/manage/vehicles
domain.com/admin/manage/drivers
domain.com/admin/manage/passengers
```

But as an alternative, you can use the the 2nd way too.

```
domain.com/admin/manage-vehicles
domain.com/admin/manage-drivers
domain.com/admin/manage-passengers
```

- Hyphens are recommended by Google over underscores [(source)](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329).
- Hyphens are more familiar to the end user.

And last of all, underscores and keyword joins are not recommended in URLs.

```
domain.com/admin/manage_vehicles
domain.com/admin/manageVehicles
```